# replace several values in a vector in R

Tags: r, vector

Let's say I have a vector

`target <- c(19,15,12,21,20,9,15,14)`

Now, I want to replace all values in that vector with other values, let's say with the corresponding letters. So, I know what values look before...

`before <- 1:26`

and I know how they are supposed to look afterwards...

`after <- letters[1:26]`

Now, I want to replace all values in `target` that equal a value in `before` with the corresponding value in `after`. I want to do this using a functional (e.g. an apply function), to get this:

```
someFancyFunction(target, before, after)

[1] "s" "o" "l" "u" "t" "i" "o" "n"
```

My best idea is using `mapply()`

```
myFun <- function(x,y,z){
    x[x==y] <- z
    x
}

mapply(myFun, y = before, z = after, MoreArgs = list(x = target))
```

But this, of course returns a matrix, while I want all iterations to be applied to the very same vector. Can anyone help?

Just to be sure. I know how to edit subsetted vectors and I know how to do it with a loop. I would just really like to do it with a functional.

Comment: Just use `after[target]`

Comment: You can Vectorize() your function for y and z

Comment: Generalizing @akrun's solution: `after[match(target,before)]`.

Comment: To expand on akrun's answer (and this question is certainly a duplicate) you are attempting to re-invent the "[" function. Can write his answer as `"["(letters, target <- c(19,15,12,21,20,9,15,14) )`. `mapply won't succeed because the lengths of target and after are not the same.

Comment: Also look at `chartr`

Comment: Thank you very much. Nicolas solution is very helpful. It solves the problem and might be easily extendable to ranges as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution - elegant, fast, readable:

```
after[match(target,before)]
```

It is actually not my solution, but @nicola 's (see comments to the question). If (s)he posts the same answer I will be happy to remove mine.